# How do I read in a file such that for each line that contains a certain string, save the lines underneath to a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, bufferedreader

I admit this might be a simple question but I cannot seem to map my head around it. Say that I have a .txt file that I'm reading with a BufferedReader in Java that might look like this:

```
Category: Dairy
Yogurt
Cheese
Butter
Category: Vegetables
Carrots
Cucumbers
Category: Snacks
Granola Bars
Trail Mix
Chips
Candy
Pop Tarts
```

I want to create a HashMap, for example, called *groceries* that will map the items to its respective category. For example:

```
groceries.put("item", "category");
```

How do I read this file in such a way that keeps track of which item belongs to which category so I can place it into the HashMap in a meaningful way? Here is a rough idea of what I have tried so far. (I tried initially with ArrayLists but figured out HashMaps might be better to map the data)

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("Category")){
                
                  (save in an arrayList() called Category)

            }
            else{
                  (save in arrayList() called Item)
            }
        }
```

Again that is just what I had originally tried. Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: If you are doing this just for fun or to learn, you'll learn the most if you just keep going in the direction you are going. If this is for something more than that, I'd recommend you transform your text file into JSON or XML format. There are plenty of resources to load data structured in these formats directly into Java.

Comment: Voted to close as needs more focus. There's more than one right answer on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can inspire (before anyone closes it ):
The structure you want to build is a map (key-value structure) not a list.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
String line;
String currentCategory = "";
Map<String, String> groceries = new HashMap<>();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("Category: ")) {
        currentCategory = line.substring(10);
    } else {
        groceries.put(line, currentCategory);
    }
}
```